# How to load insert scripts for multiple tables which are linked with foreign key in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot. I am loading test data through yml by defining spring.datasource.data=classpath:/test-data/sql_file_EntityOne.sql, classpath:/test-data/sql_file_EntityTwo.sql,...

For every single entity it works seamlessly but problem comes when EntityOne and EntityTwo have foreign key relationship and the corresponding insert statements are written in 2 different SQL files as depicted above.
I am using in memory h2 dB for local.

sql_file_EntityOne.sql
(Id_One, data_1,data_2) values(101, 'dat', 5)

sql_file_EntityTwo.sql
(Id_two, Id_One*this is fk*, data_3,data_4) 
values(1,101, 'dat2', null, 5)

EntityOne
@Id
IdOne
....
@OneToMany(Cascade.All, mappedBy="entityOneRef")
List entityTwoRef

EntityTwo
@Id
IdTwo
....
@ManyToOne(Cascade.All)
@JoinColumn("entityTwoRef")
EntityOne entityOneRef

Answer (score 0):

Can you please mention the error you are getting here?

Comment: DataIntegrity violation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following hibernate annotations for bidirectional relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = ) on parent enity

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = , nullable = false) on child entity
```

for example, let's take an example of **Cart** and **Item** as two entities with a Cart related as one to many with item:

```
//Cart 

@Entity
@Data
public class Cart {
    @Id
    private Integer cartId;
    @Column
    private String data;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<Item> items;

}

//Item
@Entity
@Data
public class Item {
    @Id
    private Integer itemId;
    @Column
    private String data;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;

}
```

@Data is just lombok annotation for getters and setters. Scripts as below:

```
//Script1
INSERT INTO CART(cart_id,data) VALUES (101,'data1')

//Script2
INSERT INTO ITEM(item_id,cart_id,data) VALUES (1,101,'data2')
```

Then load the scripts in spring-boot in order:

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:sql_script1.sql,classpath:sql_script2.sql
```

Hope it helps :)